# Simple Pendulum with Arbitrary Velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

I tried my hand at analytically solving the simple pendulum, and got an expression for its motion for arbitrary position and velocity. It matches with the expression found [here](http://sbfisica.org.br/rbef/pdf/070707.pdf) exactly, which is for arbitrary position, and also matches the small angle approximation with small angular velocity and position. However, I haven't been able to find an expression with both arbitrary position and velocity to test mine against. The finding of such an expression in the literature would be most appreciated.

Comment: Let me see if I understood your question: You are trying to solve the nonlinear simple pendulum for some velocity completely arbitrary and you want to some kind of connection between the position occupied by the body and it’s velocity. Is that it?

Comment: Not exactly. I found my own solution, and want to double check myself. However, I can’t find another exact model that takes into account arbitrary initial amplitude and angular velocity to double check myself, and I asked to find one in the literature. Sorry for the confusion.